# Migrar dados de uma tabela de DB1 para outra tabela do banco DB2

Tags: sql-server

Possuo 2 bancos de dados no **Sql Server** DB_1 e DB_2 sendo DB_2 um clone de DB_1

Estou tentando migrar todos os dados da tabela Ignition do DB_2(dados mais antigo) para a tabela Ignition do DB_1(dados mais recente) de forma que os dados venham de forma ordenada

Exemplo

```
DB_1

Table_Ignition
 IMEI  | TimeStamp  | Value |
123456 | 1581405980 | false |
123456 | 1581406335 | true  |
123456 | 1581413214 | false |
123456 | 1581413271 | true  |
123456 | 1581413274 | false |


DB_2
Table_Ignition
 IMEI  | TimeStamp  | Value |
123456 | 1577534767 | true  |
123456 | 1577534951 | false |
123456 | 1577535203 | true  |
123456 | 1577535266 | false |
123456 | 1577535287 | true  |
```

Resultado final seria algo do tipo

```
DB_1

    Table_Ignition
     IMEI  | TimeStamp  | Value |
    123456 | 1577534767 | true  |
    123456 | 1577534951 | false |
    123456 | 1577535203 | true  |
    123456 | 1577535266 | false |
    123456 | 1577535287 | true  |
    123456 | 1581405980 | false |
    123456 | 1581406335 | true  |
    123456 | 1581413214 | false |
    123456 | 1581413271 | true  |
    123456 | 1581413274 | false |
```

pensei em criar uma API para fazer essa tarefa.

Existe algo mais pratico de ser feito ?

Comment: @IvanFerrer `mysqldump` para `SQL Server`?

Comment: Opa, sqlserverdump foi mal!

Comment: Qual o motivo de não usar [sqlserverdump](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sqlserverdump) se ambas são iguais?

Answer (score 1):

A ordenação dos dados não importa, você deve definir explicitamente a ordem que deseja usando a cláusula `ORDER BY` no `SELECT`. Para inserir de um banco para outro você realizar a inserção desta forma:

```
INSERT INTO [DB_1].[dbo].[Table_Ignition](IMEI, TimeStamp, Value)
SELECT IMEI,
       TimeStamp,
       Value
  FROM [DB_2].[dbo].[Table_Ignition]
```